# Transfer data from Fragment Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, bundle, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I'm working with a bluetooth service in my application which ables me to get received message from another device. In my FragmentActivity, i'm using a handler to get this message:

FragmentActivity:

```
  public final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {

                  //my code

                  case MESSAGE_READ:
                         byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                         byte[] alpha = null;
                         alpha=readBuf;

                         if(alpha!=null){
                          //my code..
              }
        }
  }
```

From this Handler I would like to get a data and transfer it to a Fragment.
I tried to use bundle but it doesn't work..

The code I tried:

In FragmentActivity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), General.class);
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("battery", bat);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", bundle);
```

In Fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
int mLabel = bundle.getInt("battery", 0);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "tottiti: "+mLabel, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "prout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The application is returning "prout" which means that it can't get my data from my FragmentActivity.

Is there any other way to get a data frome a fragmentActivity and transfer it to a fragment?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you need pass the data to the fragment at creation time, you could use `setArguments()` to pass data to the fragment, and `getArguments()` to read that data.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("battery", bat);
MyFragment fragment=new MyFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Then in `onCreate()` method of the fragment:

```
Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 
int mLabel = bundle.getInt("battery", 0);
```

But if the fragment is already created, then you could create a method inside the fragment that you'll use to pass data, something like this:

```
fragment.setBattery(bat);
```

Comment: In fact, to have my battery data, i have to use a button in my option menu (which is in my FragmentActivity) which get the battery status of the connected device. Then in my Fragment I have a button, when I click on this button, i want my program to get the value of the battery statud that I get in the fragmentActivity.. I tried your code with some changes but it doesn't work.

Comment: I can't use ft.add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment); because i haven't define an id for my fragment. I can't get the data at the creation time because I need to use my button to get this data..

Comment: Hm.. try to store the battery data in the activity. Have a field in your `FragmentActivity` that when the option menu is clicked, will store the data there. Then when the button from the `Fragment` is clicked read that field: `((MyActivity)getActivity()).getBatteryData()`

Comment: Is it possible to use getPreferences to do thaht? because in my option menu i have already saved my battery data in getPreferences: In my option menu I have: getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("passInfo", String.valueOf(bat)).commit();  Then can I get this data in my Fragment?

Comment: If so, then yes, you probably could read if from SharedPreferences.

Comment: I 'll try to find some info about how to do that, if you have an example please show me. thank you

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's working with SharedPreferences!