# How to pass value from Activity to Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Currently this is my **Activity Class**

```
Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentTripPlan();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentCulturalHistorical();
            Toast.makeText(this, "cultural", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentLeisureRecreational();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Leisure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new FragmentLipaChurches();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new FragmentNaturalSite();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
            FragmentNaturalSite fragobj = new FragmentNaturalSite();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new FragmentCreateReport();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new FragmentAbout();
            break;

        default:
            break;
```

and Here is my **Fragment Class**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lipa_churches, container, false);   
    // ******* vvvvvv
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String strtext = bundle .getString("edttext");
return rootView;
}
```

and i got this **error** in **Log Trace**

```
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at com.c4a.itravellipaph.FragmentLipaChurches.onCreateView(FragmentLipaChurches.java:26)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-10 13:51:43.020: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Questions.

1. How can I fix this?
2. How to pass values or data from activity to fragment?
3. Is there other way to pass value?

Comment: i guess it should be  `fragment.setArguments(bundle);`

Comment: @SBerg413 i think its not. but thanks.

Comment: check this link i think helpful(Passing string in Fragment)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875804/transfer-data-from-fragment-activity-to-fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know who is `fragobj` but at `case 4` I think you have a typo, instead of:

```
FragmentLipaChurches fragobj = new FragmentLipaChurches();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

you should have:

```
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

At least `FragmentLipaChurches` should be handled differently since you're creating there an instance of `FragmentNaturalSite` but you're setting the arguments to `FragmentLipaChurches`. So `FragmentNaturalSite` doesn't have the arguments set, that's why the NPE.

Comment: so do i still need to include this in my code? or should i remove it?


**FragmentLipaChurches fragobj = new FragmentLipaChurches();**

Comment: replace **FragmentNaturalSite fragobj = new FragmentNaturalSite();fragobj.setArguments(bundle);** with **fragment.setArguments(bundle);**

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           Bundle b = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
           String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");  
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoryfragment, container, false);
           return view;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

to pass value from activity use this

```
Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putString("pathimage", path);
fragment_setting.setArguments(bun);
```

to get the vlue use this in your onCreateView in fragment

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
String path = b.getString("pathimage");
```

Comment: I still get the same log trace error.